# How to add EventHandler to DoubleAnimation end?

Tags: c#, animation, event-handling

I'm doing a `DoubleAnimation` not using the `StoryBoard` and I'm trying to apply an event handler to when it's finished (otherwise code I'm trying to do is happening before animation ends)

I have used :

```
da = new DoubleAnimation(40,20,  new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));

((PerspectiveCamera)_Main3D.Camera).
    BeginAnimation(PerspectiveCamera.FieldOfViewProperty, da);

da.Completed += new EventHandler(Story_Completed);
```

Yet this event never occours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attaching an event handler **after** you start the animation. If the animation is brief then it's possible that it finishes before the Completed handler is ever assigned. It's also possible that the animation object doesn't respond to handler assignment while running an animation.

Try this:

```
da = new DoubleAnimation(40,20,  new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));

da.Completed += new EventHandler(Story_Completed);

((PerspectiveCamera)_Main3D.Camera).
    BeginAnimation(PerspectiveCamera.FieldOfViewProperty, da);
```

...add the Competed handler before starting the animation...

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, it works. Live long and Prosper!